# How to get the object properties onclick of the element in d3.js Treemap layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In the d3 **treemap** layout onClick of any segment, how to log the clicked element object properties in the console .

Find my react and d3.js code in this link . https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-thunder-l024x

```
const dataObj = {
  name: "Home",
  children: [
    {
      name: "A",
      metricsValue: "ma",
      value: "15"
    },
    {
      name: "BCD",
      value: "35",
      metricsValue: "m1"
    }
  ]
};
```

Example : Onclick of the element **"BCD"** , log the properties of BCD in the console .

```
Result : 
{
      name: "BCD",
      value: "35",
      metricsValue: "m1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass Object in logTitle method 
and need to make some changes in index file as well

```
function logTitle(d) {          
      self.props.onClickSegment({
        name: d.name,
        value: d.value,
        metricsValue: d.metricsValue
      });
    }
```

I have made changes in ur example find it below

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-star-9vm5m

Comment: Thanks !! @manoj .. In your code the breadcrumb functionality is not going to the root node onclick .

Comment: @RenJith Missed undefined condition check for root node. I have updated code and fixed breadcrum issue.